# The constructor ArrayAdapter<String>(AddNewUnit, int, String) is undefined

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, android-context

I'm new to android and Java and I faced this problem and I search for answer but I don't find any thing.

I'm trying to get some data from database and put it in spinner but I faced this problem:

*The constructor ArrayAdapter(AddNewUnit, int, String) is undefined*

this is my code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;

public class AddNewUnit extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener {

EditText UnitName;
Spinner BookName;
DataBase dataBase;
String[][] Books;
String BookId;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.add_new_unit);
    UnitName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ANU_EtUnitName);
    BookName = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.ANU_SBookName);
    dataBase.open();
    Books = dataBase.Get_Books();
    dataBase.close();
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter =new ArrayAdapter<String>(AddNewUnit.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, Books[1][]);
    BookName.setAdapter(adapter);
    BookName.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
}
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
        long arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    BookId=Books[0][BookName.getSelectedItemPosition()];
}
@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}


}
```

My problem is with this line

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter =new ArrayAdapter<String>(AddNewUnit.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, Books[1][]);
```

I searched and  found that most mistakes is with context when they write `this` but I write `AddNewUnit.this` which is my activity.

**what's the mistake I do it?**

---

**More details:**

I'm sorry this is the first time to use java I used c++ before and in c++ I use `Books[1][]` to transform array from multidimensional to single-dimension it just get the row number 1 from the array.

This string it has two rows one for Book ID and one for Book name I want to pass just the Book name which is the row 1.

Is there any way to do that or I must use custom `ArrayAdapter`?

Comment: Will you please try with just passing String[]. I mean your problem can be at Books[1][]; Will you just create an array constant and pass and see it works or not

Comment: going good check your DB query .. getting data or not :)

Answer (score 1):

The constructor used is undefined.

`public ArrayAdapter (Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, T[] objects)`

Added in API level 1

Constructor

Parameters

```
context The current context.

resource    The resource ID for a layout file containing a layout to use when instantiating views.

textViewResourceId  The id of the TextView within the layout resource to be populated

objects The objects to represent in the ListView.
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#ArrayAdapter(android.content.Context, int, T[])

You have this

```
 ArrayAdapter<String> adapter =new ArrayAdapter<String>(AddNewUnit.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, Books[1][]);  // params wrong
```

Use a Custom Listview with custom adapter along with a view holder.

Override `getCount` and `getView`

[How to Display two dimensional Array in ListView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8666859/how-to-display-two-dimensional-array-in-listview)

Answer (score 0):

i think you will have to use `custom adapter` for `Books[1][]` because its multi dimensional !
so use `custom Adapter` and **override** `getView()`

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter =new ArrayAdapter<String>(AddNewUnit.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, Books[1][]);
```

`ArrayAdapter` doesn't have any constructor that receives 2D array. Try extending `BaseAdapter` and create your own custom adapter.

```
public class YourCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

String[][] your2Darray;

//Here's your constructor
public YourCustomAdapter(Context c,int layoutId,int resourceId, String[][] you2Darray){
        this.your2Darray=your2Darray;
....
      }
}....
```

Override `getCount()` and `getView()`.

Answer (score -1):

You have Set the T type to be string and then you pass set of Book type objects, you need to change the String to "your data class"

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Sorry boss rich formatting removed the text between "<>"